# Updating properties and states

Tags: c#, linq, properties

I am rewriting a VB.NET application in C#. This code was originally done in 50 lines and I am trying to clean it up. As you can see I have gotten it down to 10 but I still feel its ugly. I want to convert the call and assignments into one Linq statement or method chain. See Comments:

```
public void Update(IEnumerable<MyObjectproperties> properties)
    {
        var propertiesToBeUpdated = new List<MyObjectproperties>();
        //I am convinced I can do this in one linq statement
        foreach (var output in properties)
        {
            var outputToBeUpdated = _context.MyObjectProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == output.Key);
            outputToBeUpdated.propertiesName = output.propertiesName;
            outputToBeUpdated.propertiesValue = output.propertiesValue;
            propertiesToBeUpdated.Add(outputToBeUpdated);
        }

        _context.Entry(propertiesToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What I am hoping this method looks like when I am done is:

```
public void Update(IEnumerable<MyObjectProperties> properties)
{
    var propertiesToBeUpdated = //My new linq statement here
    _context.Entry(propertiesToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am "okay" at writing complex linq statements but this one is a bit more than I can handle (assuming its possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var propertiesToBeUpdated = properties.Select(p => {
    var prop = _context.MyObjectProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == output.Key);

    return prop == null ? null :
        new MyObjectProperties {
            Key = prop.propertiesKey,
            Name = prop.propertiesName,
            Value = prop.propertiesValue
        };
}).Where(p => p != null);
```

The extra set of `{}` inside your LINQ statement allow you to do multiple lines. If for some reason, you're going to be absolutely POSITIVE that `prop` would never be null, it would simplify the LINQ a lot more by not having to return nulls (since you have to return SOMETHING for each item in the collection you're iterating). You also then wouldn't need the `Where()` at the end as well.

**UPDATE**

If it will never be null, then it is even simpler:

```
var propertiesToBeUpdated = properties.Select(p => {
    var prop = _context.MyObjectProperties.First(x => x.Key == output.Key);

    return new MyObjectProperties {
            Key = prop.propertiesKey,
            Name = prop.propertiesName,
            Value = prop.propertiesValue
        };
});
```

Comment: I am certain that it would never be null.

Comment: I would give you an extra +1 if I could. I was not aware you could add curly braces to allow for extra code lines in a single linq query.

Comment: That's true of all delegates.